# How to print results from multiple arrays simanteously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I have a problem printing out multiple array values in sequential order from each array index. I have three arrays I want to iterate over only once. The `$.each()` function iterates over the entire array three times assuming there are three arrays defined in the selector prarameter of the `$.each()`. Here's my code and output in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnksv4zp/).

```
var _videoIdArr = ["via1","via2", "via3", "via4", "via5"];
var _vidTitleArr = ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"]; 
var _viewCountArr = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"]; 

// loop thru multiple arrays and print total values
$.each([_videoIdArr, _vidTitleArr, _viewCountArr], function()
{
   $.each(this, function(i, item)
   {
      // construct the div
      vidThumbnail = '<div class="video">ID: ' + _videoIdArr[i] + '<br/>Title: ' + _vidTitleArr[i] + '<br/>Count: ' + _viewCountArr[i] + '</div>';
     console.log(vidThumbnail);

     // print the div
     $('.section.video > .thumb').append(vidThumbnail);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a classic `for` loop? Provided that there three arrays have the same length as it seems it should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _videoIdArr.length; i++) {
  vidThumbnail = '<div class="video">ID: ' + _videoIdArr[i] + '<br/>Title: ' + _vidTitleArr[i] + '<br/>Count: ' + _viewCountArr[i] + '</div>';
  console.log(vidThumbnail);

  // print the div
  $('.section.video > .thumb').append(vidThumbnail);
}
```

or if you want to use `$.each` you can just use the index variable:

```
$.each(_videoIdArr, function(i) {
  vidThumbnail = '<div class="video">ID: ' + _videoIdArr[i] + '<br/>Title: ' + _vidTitleArr[i] + '<br/>Count: ' + _viewCountArr[i] + '</div>';
  console.log(vidThumbnail);

  // print the div
  $('.section.video > .thumb').append(vidThumbnail);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all arrays have the same lengths and there are no missing properties, you only need one `each` loop:

```js
var _videoIdArr = ["via1", "via2", "via3", "via4", "via5"];
var _vidTitleArr = ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"];
var _viewCountArr = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"];

// loop thru multiple arrays and print total values

$.each(_videoIdArr, function(i, item) {
  // construct the div
  vidThumbnail = '<div class="video">ID: ' + _videoIdArr[i] + '<br/>Title: ' + _vidTitleArr[i] + '<br/>Count: ' + _viewCountArr[i] + '</div>';
  console.log(vidThumbnail);

  // print the div
  $('body').append(vidThumbnail);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.concat()` `,`.apply()` to combine all arrays into single array

```
$.each([].concat.apply([], [_videoIdArr, _vidTitleArr, _viewCountArr])
, function(i, item) {
  // construct the div
  var vidThumbnail = '<div class="video">ID: ' 
                     + item + '<br/>Title: ' 
                     + item + '<br/>Count: ' 
                     + item + '</div>';
  console.log(vidThumbnail);

  // print the div
  $('.section.video > .thumb').append(vidThumbnail);
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jnksv4zp/1/